# Dynamically configure a Job in spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Is it possible to dynamically configure a `Job` in `spring-batch`?

Here is what I want to do. I have created several different `ItemReader`, `ItemWriter` like below:

- FlatFileItemReader
- DBItemReader
- FlatFileItemWriter
- DBItemWriter
- .....
- XMLItemWriter

I want to be able to mix and match them dynamically while creating a batch Job. For example, suppose I need a Job with 2 steps. First step contains a `Tasklet` for *pre-processing*. Second Step will have a `Tasklet` for chunk based data processing using my reader/writer.... Something like this:

```
// define job parameters
JobParametersBuilder parameters = new JobParametersBuilder();

// create two steps
TaskletStep step1 = new TaskletStep(); 
TaskletStep step2 = new TaskletStep();
step1.setName("PreProcessingStep");
step2.setName("ChunkReadWriteStep");

// create two TaskLets
Tasklet tasklet1 = new PreProcessingTasklet();
Tasklet tasklet2; <------ HOW DO I ATTACH MY reader/writer IN THIS TASKLET??

// attach the TaskLet to the step
step1.setTasklet(tasklet1);
step2.setTasklet(tasklet2);

// attach the steps to the job
SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob("MyBatchJob");
job.addStep(step1);
job.addStep(step2); 

jobLauncher.run(job, parameters.toJobParameters());
```

In XML, I can do this like below:

```
<job id="MyBatchJob">
    <step id="preprocessing" next="readWriteStep">
        <tasklet ref="PreProcessingTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="readWriteStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="FlatFileItemReader" writer="DBItemWriter"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

But how do I do it programatically like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Batch provides java based configuration for the building of jobs via java code instead of XML.  By using the provided builders, you can dynamically construct jobs as you need.  I'd strongly suggest using this method instead of wiring a `ChunkOrientedTasklet` by hand since there is quite a bit going on in that particular `Tasklet`.

The best place to get started with Spring Batch's java configuration is in the Spring Batch guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/.  It's a 15 minute walk through on getting started with Spring Batch using tools like Spring Boot and java configuration.

Comment: ok... before I shift my focus to Java based configuration.. could this problem be also resolved by parameterising the reader and writer in XML? If yes, will there be any disadvantage?

Comment: I don't believe we support the ability to parameterize those fields.  That being said, how dynamic do you need these to be?  It may make more sense to define a collection of steps and just choose which one to execute at runtime.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but from a collection of pre-defined steps in XML, how do I attach one appropriate `step` to execute at runtime?

Comment: You can use a decision step to choose which one to execute at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. After going through the Spring Batch guide example you mentioned above, I have kind of decided to use the java based configuration now!

Comment: @MichaelMinella I now this is an old question, but let's say i want steps to be added or removed based on some configuration. It's possible to do it when constructing the Job right? or do you think it would be better to have different job definitions and somehow inject the correct one based on a qualifier? I don't want to change the 'client' code where the job is injected with Autowired.

Comment: @AntonioDias please create a new question and I'll respond there.

Comment: @MichaelMinella ok, i posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658298/spring-batch-dynamic-flow-job-construction

Thanks